# If I want to create an ERC20 token , is it better to add underlying business logic in the token contract itself?

Tags: solidity, ether

I want to implement ERC20 token which needs to be mined or burnt based on few business logics. Should I implement those logic in the token contract itself or implement it in the separate contract. Also is it better to implement business logic in smart contracts or implement them on centralized backend system?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to create an ERC20 is to use the Open Zeppelin wizard:

https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/

A smart contract logic is always onchain, and not on a backend server so all logic would normally be onchain. Of course, you can also use a bot that would call functions on the contract externally.

I recommend going through this post and watching the YouTube videos related to the solidity by example to get a good grasp on how contracts should function.

https://solidity-by-example.org/app/erc20/